# AWS Sagemaker Cant train my Keras model - ErrorMemoryError: Unable to allocate 20 GiB for an array with shape and data type

Tags: amazon-web-services, keras, amazon-sagemaker

it's my very first time using AWS Sagemaker, so I'm trying to fit my keras model and get this error the whole time. I don't know how can I solve it , I tried doing  echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory but then kernel died. I was using the most basic and cheapest version for Sagemaker, I think it has 4GB ,may it be the problem?
But I dont really know with this configuration I can fit this model in my own computer, so that means that Sagemaker has less power than my computer?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a model that requires a 20GB array to be stored, you'd probably want to use something like an ml.t3.2xlarge or ml.m5.8xlarge instance, which have 32GB of memory available.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

**Method 1**

You can select this from the SageMaker Studio environment if you're using the SM Studio IDE, via the "Switch instance type" button at the top of your notebook tab.

Once you've done this, the instance list will appear in a pop up, and you need to click on the "Fast launch only" selector button, so that you can see all available instance types.

**Method 2**

Alternatively, if you're using a "traditional" SageMaker Jupyter notebook without the SageMaker Studio IDE:

Goto the main SageMaker console.

Click on Notebook -> Notebook Instances.

Click on the hyperlink of the notebook you want to change the instance type for.

This will take you to the "Notebook instance settings" page.

Click on the "Edit" button (top right).

Select your new, larger instance type from the "Notebook instance type" drop down list.

Scroll down to the bottom of the page and click on the "Update notebook instance" button.

This will take you back to your list of notebook instances.
Note that the list will contain the word "Updating", with a clock icon next to it in the Status column.

If this hasn't refreshed after a few minute, click on your browser refresh button.

The instance should now show as being available/In Service, with the new instance size/type listed in the "Instance" column.

If it's not started, click on the "Start" link in the "Actions" column and it should start with the new instance type.